# Need ideas to move a server from one subnet to another subnet withing the same datacenter?

Tags: networking, routing, load-balancing, subnet

We have a Oracle production instance running in application subnet where multiple application are accessing the database from within the subnet(172.17.x.x), Unfortunately, the database is very old and all application are connecting it using the IP address and not using DNS name. I dont know what are all the application that are connecting to the database. We have a requirement to move the database to another subnet within same location (10.52.x.x). But the application will remain in the other subnet. I want to know what are all the mechanism to move the database without to affecting the IP address suppose 172.17.178.100. Please suggest

I have suggested a F5 load balancer for oracle database to be used in the primary subnet with front end IP(172.17.178.100) and map it to the backend IP address of the new database instance of the secondary subnet. Please suggest all alternative solution as I have limited knowledge in terms of networking.

Comment: Well, the "cleanest" way would be to switch all applications to DNS first and move then. If your applications use any form of TNSNAMES you can change the connection string there. If you want to go the NAT-route, you don't need anything as big as F5 (I suppose, but I don't know your server's load). A small and simple machine just for NAT would suffice, maybe. So your suggestion is viable, but maybe a bit over the top.

Comment: Thanks, the second suggestion seems viable because application is accessing using multiple endpoints JDBC,ETL,DB Links and the database is as old as 15 years and no proper documentation is there of all the interfacing, also the database dont have any access logs configured due to storage limitation. Hence  we need to use a proxy solution as of now

Answer (score 2):

Migrate all applications to use DNS, and **document your findings**. As you do not know all of them, this will be a discovery process.

Configure a new different IP address on the host and put that in DNS as the service address, `db.example.net` or so. Communicate to all possible application owners the rename project, and that things will not work if no action is taken. Set a deadline to identify and rename every interfaced system.

Inevitably something will be forgotten. Identify laggards by logging with firewall rules remaining connections to the existing `172.17.178.100` IP. Do some investigation on these, and send increasingly urgent reminders to owners of whatever you find.

That was the hard work. Actually moving IPs will probably be relatively easy. Follow your checklist to re-IP the server and update the DNS name.

---

While updating to network technologies of this decade, insist the vendors support IPv6. Plentiful global address space prevents subnets from running out or overlapping.

Comment: Having deployed IPv6 internally, even without global connectivity, may have allowed his company to avoid this renumbering problem entirely.

Answer (score 1):

@John Mahowald's suggestions are sound, especially logging the IPs that connect to 172.17.178.100 to determine which hosts are still using the old IP.

Depending on your situation, it may be possible to tunnel the IP you require from the old subnet to the new one.  This could be helpful if you are under a deadline to complete the move of the server to the new 10.52.x.y subnet, and do not have time to get everyone to stop using the old IP before you make the move.  The technique described below can make the 172.17.178.100 accessible to your users even though the server has physically moved to the new 10.52.x.y subnet.

I have used this technique in the past to make a DNS server available on two IPs simultaneously -- its new IP in a new location, and its old legacy IP from a separate subnet in a different location.  I was then able to log the remote hosts that were still using the old IP, and migrate them to using the new IP, without having to rush to avoid any potential downtime.

The necessary ingredient is a host that is **still** on the legacy subnet, and which must remain on that subnet until you complete your migration from the old IP number to the new IP (or better, the new DNS name).  I'll call that machine A, the "A end" and/or subnet A throughout.

Machine B then lives in the new subnet (Subnet B), and has a normal IP address in subnet B.  Machine B will eventually be provisioned with the old IP, and traffic from the old subnet will be re-routed to Machine B via a tunnel.

When I implemented this (for about a 3-month transition period), it was on FreeBSD, so the syntax here is BSD-specific.  The setup below may sound a little gnarly, but a lot of it is my own over-description.  It's only 5 command lines or fewer, that can be put in a script and added to your boot-time startup configuration.  Assuming that both the old subnet and new subnet are in the same datacenter and use a secure routing path that does not expose your traffic to the public internet, the security implications should be fairly small.  If the traffic to 172.17.178.100 is or isn't already encrypted, it will remain encrypted (or unencrypted) using this method.  I'm not a security expert, but that seems like a "no net change" outcome.  This method should **not** be used for senstive traffic that is tunneled over an insecure network (such as the internet) on its way from Machine A to Machine B.

For a more secure and complete treatment of this concept, see the [FreeBSD Handbook entry on VPN over IPSec](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ipsec.html), on which this idea is based.

## The A end: IP 172.17.178.105, internal tunnel IP 192.168.255.1

```
# sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
# arp -s 172.17.178.100 78:2b:cb:3a:f6:93 pub
# ifconfig gif0 create
# ifconfig gif0 192.168.255.1 192.168.255.2
# ifconfig gif0 tunnel 172.17.178.105 10.52.100.200
# route add 172.17.178.100 192.168.255.2
```

Breaking those down:

The A end will be required to forward packets across interfaces, so the correct `sysctl` setting is required:

```
# sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

Make that permanent with:

```
# echo 'net.inet.ip.forwarding=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Determine the Subnet A MAC address of Machine A and publish an ARP proxy entry using that same MAC address and the old IP, 172.17.178.100:

```
# arp -s 172.17.178.100 78:2b:cb:3a:f6:93 pub
```

Then we create a `gif` interface and configure the `gif` tunnel with the local IP and remote IP (in that order).  Note that these are the "internal" IPs of the tunnel.  They are not visible to the outside world, and are used only for routing the traffic from machine A to machine B.

```
# ifconfig gif0 create
# ifconfig gif0 192.168.255.1 192.168.255.2
```

You should choose RFC1939 IP addresses which are not in use at your datacenter.  192.168.255.1 is the inside IP of the tunnel's A end, and 192.168.255.2 is the inside IP of the B end.

Next we define the **outside** IPs of the tunnel ends.

```
# ifconfig gif0 tunnel 172.17.178.105 10.52.100.200
```

Here 172.17.178.105 is the Subnet A IP of Machine A.  That's why I say this method requires a system that will "stay behind" in the A subnet, while your application IP 172.17.178.100 undergoes migration to the new location and subnet B.

The final command on Machine A is to route traffic for the legacy IP to the remote (B end) **internal** tunnel IP:

```
# route add 172.17.178.100 192.168.255.2
```

## The B end: IP 10.52.100.200, internal tunnel IP 192.168.255.2

Now, let's move to the B end configuration.  No ARP proxying is needed, nor is any special routing, so the setup is only three commands instead of five:

```
# ifconfig gif0 create
# ifconfig gif0        192.168.255.2 192.168.255.1
# ifconfig gif0 tunnel 10.52.100.200 172.17.178.105
```

Notice that the IP numbers are reversed from what we used on the A end.  The first IP is the local one, and the second IP is the remote one.  So from the B end, the
local-end **inside** IP is 192.168.255.2, and the remote-end inside IP is 192.168.255.1.  Likewise, the physical (external) IPs are 10.52.100.200 on the B end, and 172.17.178.105 on the A end.

## Checking the Configuration

On the A end, you should see:

```
# ifconfig gif0
gif0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1280
        options=80000<LINKSTATE>
        tunnel inet 172.17.178.105 --> 10.52.100.200
        inet6 fe80::7a2b:cbff:fe3a:f693%gif0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8 
        inet 192.168.255.1 --> 192.168.255.2  netmask 0xffff0000 
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        groups: gif
```

The B end `gif0` interface will be the same, but with the IPs reversed:

```
gif0: flags=8051<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1280
        options=80000<LINKSTATE>
        tunnel inet 10.52.100.200 --> 172.17.178.105
        inet 192.168.255.2 --> 192.168.255.1 netmask 0xffff0000
        groups: gif
```

From A, you should be able to ping the inside IP of the remote tunnel endpoint:

```
# ping -c3 192.168.255.2
PING 192.168.255.2 (192.168.255.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.255.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.348 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.255.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.394 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.255.2: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.400 ms

--- 192.168.255.2 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.348/0.381/0.400/0.023 ms
```

From B, likewise, you should be able to reach the inside IP of the A end of the tunnel:

```
# ping -c3 192.168.255.1
PING 192.168.255.1 (192.168.255.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.255.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.342 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.255.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.410 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.255.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.383 ms

--- 192.168.255.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.342/0.378/0.410/0.028 ms
```

The only thing left is to provision the old IP 172.17.178.100 on Machine B.  Let's assume Machine B's interface is bge0.

```
# ifconfig bge0 add 172.17.178.100/32
```

Now, from Machine A (or indeed, any machine), you should be able to ping 172.17.178.100.

## Summary

On Machine A:

```
sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
# substitute Machine A's MAC address here:
arp -s 172.17.178.100 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx pub

ifconfig gif0 create
ifconfig gif0        192.168.255.1 192.168.255.2
ifconfig gif0 tunnel 172.17.178.105 10.52.100.200

route add 172.17.178.100 192.168.255.2
```

On Machine B:

```
ifconfig gif0 create
ifconfig gif0        192.168.255.2 192.168.255.1
ifconfig gif0 tunnel 10.52.100.200 172.17.178.105
ifconfig bge0 add 172.17.178.100/32
```

## Alternatives

If the above isn't what you prefer to do, it may be possible to ask your datacenter network engineers to provide you with a [trunked ethernet port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunking#VLAN).  This would require that SubNet A and Subnet B can be accessed through different VLANs.  Inquire with your network engineers to find out.    Machine B would need to have a VLAN-aware network adapter and the network configuration would need to be adjusted to configure the 10.52.x.x VLAN separately from the 172.17.178.x VLAN.  The downside to this is that it imposes costs on the datacenter network engineers, who may or may not have the time or inclination to assist you.  OTOH, the `gif` interface tunneling method requires **no** outside assistance, except for permission to leave Machine A online and connected to Subnet A for the length of time that it takes you to complete the migration.

Answer (score 0):

Loose ideas:

1. Maybe setting up routing on l3 switch is enough
2. Try to use haproxy as load balancer between networks
3. Use second network interface ( or even up address on the same interface) and start project of redesigning of applications
4. Set up second oracle and replicate ( just joking. Nobody buy *second* oracle. All we are learning).